# Repercussions of disabling file read and write in Adobe Flash player?

Tags: file-upload, flash

There are three settings in `mms.cfg` that I want to disable. It will disable file download and upload for Adobe Flash, but does it have any deeper issues?

```
LocalFileReadDisable = 1
FileDownloadDisable = 1
FileUploadDisable = 1
```

File uploads and downloads does not seem to be a problem since we can whitelist domains by setting this:

```
FileDownloadEnabledDomain = domain name or IP address
```

But what about disabling local file read? For security reasons I want to disable it, but I am afraid that it will break things.

Comment: What do you mean with "does it have deeper issues"? Do you want to know if it will break functionality? Or do you want to know if it will protect you against some exploit? Not sure I understand what you are asking.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you after the security implications?

Comment: I want to understand the impact of disabling this. From security recommendations it should be done right ? but if I do what will break ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It breaks most SWFs. The issue is with `LoadVars.Load()`. This functions was widely used in Flash files. You need to check with your vendors on this.

From the [Adobe Support](https://helpx.adobe.com/adobe-media-server/ssaslr/loadvars-class.html#loadvars_load):

> Downloads variables from the specified URL, parses the variable data,
>   and places the resulting variables into the LoadVars object that calls
>   the method. You can load variables from a remote URL or from a URL in
>   the local file system; the same encoding standards apply to both.

Also see [this reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as2/reference/flashlite/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118cd9b5f6e-7932.html).

Comment: Superb, i think i will stay away from LocalFileReadDisable